# how to define long type variable in xml file in Android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I have been writing this code in Android studio .java file to calculate time for a task:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
doLongThing();
long difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
long fulltime = difference /1000;
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.The_Time), fulltime);
```

I added this line into my string.xml:

```
<string name="The_Time"> The process took $fulltime </string>
```

and This textview in the Activity main:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:text="@string/The_Time"/>
```

But I keep getting the result in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Vnj.png).  What am I doing wrong? The number of milliseconds is not displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use string value this way:

```
<string name="The_Time"> The process took %1$d </string>
```

Comment: it keeps displaying "The process took %1$d".. i dont know what to do im so desperate.

Comment: @Fatima Are you setting formatted text to `TextView`?  `((TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view_id)).setText(text);`